# Group of Lie type as expanders: explicit estimates

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, expander-graphs

In a paper [Finite simple groups as expanders](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/16/6116.short) by M. Kassabov, A. Lubotzky and N. Nikolov there is a theorem, stating that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for every non-abelian finite simple group of Lie type (except the Suzuki group) its Cayley graph with respect to some $k$ elements generating set is an $\varepsilon$-expander. Then there is a line:

> In fact careful estimates using variations of some of the arguments
>   below yield $k < 1,000$ and $\varepsilon > 10^{-10}$.

The proof is scattered over the extensive volume of literature and seems to have many places amenable to improvements, a lot of them concerning the resulting estimates. I wonder if anyone has managed to compile some sort of "dependencies tree": what effect does each part of the proof has on the bounds.

An example: if $G=H_1H_2\ldots H_n$, and each subgroup $H_i$ is an $\varepsilon$-expander (w.r.t. $S_i$), then $G$ is an $\varepsilon'$-expander (w.r.t. $\cup_i S_i$). How exactly does $\varepsilon'$ depends on $\varepsilon$, $n$ and $|S_i|$?